# How do I hook a wirelessly connected DLNA TV to my desktop computer?

Tags: networking, tv, dlna

I have a Sony LCD TV that is DLNA certified and I want to be able to access the music files from my desktop computer and play them through me television.

The two are on opposite ends of the house so there is no way to connect using cable.

I have Uverse internet with a modem / router.  How would I connect the two, computer and televsion to be able to access my music files and play them through the music folder on the TV?

Comment: You want to look into creating dlna server on yuour pc and point your tv to it

Comment: This is a complex problem and some more detail may be required.  For instance, do the TV and router support WiFi?  What OS is on the computer?  Providing answers based on assumptions is not in anyone's best interest.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run a DLNA server on your desktop computer. This would assume that your TV and computer are both connected to the Internet through the same wireless router. A google search for 'dlna server' and your operating system should get your started. You may also want to do a search for your Brand/Series of TV since not all DLNA client implementations work the same. Sony may also have some software available to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have them both connect to the same wireless network. Your TV either has a wireless network card built-in, or it is available as a separate device (you'll need to buy that, then). If you have a normal Ethernet cable, you can also connect the TV directly to one of the router's LAN ports, but as since you said that cable is no option, you will eventually have to go with WiFi.

Consult the TV's manual on how to connect it to your network.

Your computer should already be connected to the wireless network.

In order to stream media from your computer to the TV, you need a DLNA capable UPnP media server. [There are so many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_UPnP_AV_media_servers) of them, just choose one you like. [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) is very popular, for example. There are also more lightweight ones such as [MediaTomb](http://mediatomb.cc/). I personally use [TVMobili](http://www.tvmobili.com/). These are all cross-platform. Install it on your computer and add your music folder to the library.

Once you've set up the UPnP media server, your TV will be able to locate it automatically and show it under its inputs.

Note that DLNA streaming over WiFi is not very efficient. Music will play fine, but as soon as you want to stream HD movies, the performance of your network might not be sufficient to guarantee smooth playback.